# Alinear dos botones horizontalmente en misma celda

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

No consigo alinear estos dos botones en la misma celda quiero que salga uno al lado del otro y no como me salen ponga lo que ponga que es uno debajo del otro os dejo el código a ver si me podéis echar una mano con esto.

Estoy usando Laravel y una plantilla ADMINDLTE que a su vez usa BOOTSTRAP, pero no consigo nada ni con el

Gracias

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-m-12 box">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="margin box-header with-border">
              <a href="{{ url('ultimostrabajos/create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Preview</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Fecha creacion</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Titulo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Sort</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($ultimostrabajos as $listado)
                <tr>

                  <td class="text-center"><img src="/storage/{{ $listado->url }}" alt="" width="100%" height="25%"/></td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->name}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->created_at}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->titulo}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->descripcion}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->sort}}</td>
                  <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-info"> <a href="{{ route('ultimostrabajos.edit', $listado->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></button>
                           <form action="{{ route('ultimostrabajos.destroy', $listado->id) }}"  method="post">
                           @csrf
                           @method('DELETE')
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                           </form>

                  </td>
                 </tr>
                  @endforeach
              </tbody>
              </table>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de bootstrap usas la 3 o la 4?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <button class="btn btn-info mx-1"> <a href="{{ route('ultimostrabajos.edit', $listado->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></button>
    <form action="{{ route('ultimostrabajos.destroy', $listado->id) }}"  method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-1"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Si usas BS4, sencillo, creas un `div` y asignas la clase `d-flex` esto hará que tus botones se alinien. Agregué la clase `mx-1` a los botones que les da un pequeño `margin` y se vean más estéticos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo con `display: inline-block;` asi:

```css
.form-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-m-12 box">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="margin box-header with-border">
              <a href="{{ url('ultimostrabajos/create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</a>
            </div>            
            <div class="box-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Preview</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Fecha creacion</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Titulo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Sort</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>               
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center"><img src="/storage/{{ $listado->url }}" alt="" width="100%" height="25%"/></td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->name}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->created_at}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->titulo}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->descripcion}}</td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{$listado->sort}}</td>
                  <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-info"> <a href="{{ route('ultimostrabajos.edit', $listado->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></button>
                           <form action="{{ route('ultimostrabajos.destroy', $listado->id) }}"  method="post" class="form-button">
                          
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                           </form>
                  </td>
                 </tr>                 
              </tbody>
              </table>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```